# masked_blit Allegro 4.2.1

Tags: c++, allegro

when I using masked_blit function:

```
masked_blit( animations[which], buffer, 0, 0, x, y, animations[which]->w, animations[which]->h )
```

I get wrong colors on my buffer, my bmp is something like shifted or shocked.

this is my problem.

[image]

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your problem is that you are using a `video bitmap` with this call and your hardware does not support it **OR** the two bitmaps (`animations[]` and `buffer`) are different color depths.

To discard the possibility of hardware not supporting this feature, check that the `GFX_HW_VRAM_BLIT_MASKED` bit in the `gfx_capabilities` flag is set on your PC.

If they are the same color depth, but your hardware does not support the feature, you can always use the calls with `memory bitmaps` as a source, so the animations will reside in RAM instead of the video memory.

Source:

[Allegro 4.2.1 manual (pdf)](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/alleg/allegro-manual-4.2.1.en.pdf?download) - Sections **1.15.3 masked_blit** and **1.9.13 gfx_capabilities**